# Expected identifier UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

i got one error in my code and i can´t se any answer on the problem here on stack overflow so i need some help.
here´s my code

**the H- file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewWalkViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

**and here´s the m-file**

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

    UIViewController *nextController = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([nextController isKindOfClass:[NewWalkViewController]]) {
        ((NewWalkViewController *) nextController).managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    }

}

@end
```

i got the error on the if- nextController line in the m-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to modify your if statement as below..

```
if ([nextController isKindOfClass:[NewWalkViewController class]]) {
```

Just add the `class` method for NewWalkViewController class, which will return the class object